# How to catch mouse-up event outside of element?

Tags: javascript

I have simple Javascript code, similar to this one:

```
var mouseIsDown = false;
...
function canvasMouseDown(e) {
  ...
  mouseIsDown = true;
}
function canvasMouseUp(e) {
  mouseIsDown = false;
}
function canvasMouseMove(e) {
  if (mouseIsDown) {
    ...
  }
}
```

with implemention my own user interface for tranformations (translations, scalings and rotations) with canvas.

Such implementation within `canvasMouseMove()` function check `mouseIsDown` variable. All works fine if user does not release mouse button when the cursor/pointer is outside of the canvas element. If that happen, the variable `mouseIsDown` stays `true` and is not turned off by `canvasMouseUp` function.

What is easy fix or solution in pure JavaScript *(no jQuery)* for this issue?

Comment: How about if the user drags out of the viewport and releases the mouse?

Comment: @canon - Good point - do you have solution for that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to catch the `mouseup` event somewhere else in the document, you might add an event handler for this to the `documentelement`. Note that this won't react on `mouseup` events outside the viewport, so you might want to fire also when the mouse enters the viewport again without a pressed button.

If you want to catch the mouse leaving your canvas element, it gets a bit more complicated. While IE knows a `mouseleave` event, the standard DOM has a `mouseout` event that also fires when a descendant of your element is left (although canvas usually has no child elements). Read more on that at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html).

I have created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWkCT/) to demonstrate the behaviour (works only with W3 DOM). You might try to change `documentelement` to `body`. In Opera, the `mouseup` listener on `<html>` event detects `mouseup` events outside the document when the "drag" began inside it - I do not know whether that is standard behaviour.

Comment: this worked for me with a jQuery Dialog resize issue regarding iframe content in the dialog, the only difference was I assigned the mouseup handler to `document` rather than `body`

Answer (score 29):

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
// do logic here
})
```

It handle releasing mouse even outside of browser

Answer (score 10):

document.onmouseup will be thrown even outside the viewport, that's a nice-to-know you only get by binding to the document object. test here: http://jsfiddle.net/G5Xr2/

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  alert("UP" + e.pageX);
});
```

It will even receive the mouse position!

Comment: @matdumsa also does not work in current Chrome (v. 31). It overrides "which" after I re-entered the element, but not at the time when I release the mouse button.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript, it would be the following:

```
myElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  const handleMouseUp = (event) => {
    // check whether outside the element with event.target and myElement

    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
  };

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a higher-level event handler (perhaps to the body) that catches the `mouseUp` event, and sets `mouseIsDown` to `false`.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFefV/

Comment: +1 :: Thanks! :: Will body catch it even when it is released over some div element or other document elements?

Comment: @Ωmega The body element covers almost everything (the exception being when the page content does not extend to the bottom). Due to event bubbling, it should catch anything that is not handled by another handler, including unhandled clicks over other elements.

Comment: So when the page comes with CSS `body { height: 100%; }`, then I should catch that always, right?

Comment: If I recall correctly, indeed. You may also need to give the `html` element the same height.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Does not work in current Chrome (v. 31).

Answer (score 2):

I created a variable that stored the id string of the target element upon `mousedown`. On a `mouseup` event, I check the string to see if it is null. If it isn't, I use the string to get the element and do whatever I want in the code block and then reset the variable to null.

IN other words, steps are:

1.) make a variable, set it to null. 2.) on "mousedown", save the id or class string to the variable. 3.) on "mouseup", check the variable (for safety). If it's not null. then use the string to grab the element and use it to do something. 4.) Then reset the variable to null.

```
var thisTarget = null

// when I know they click in the right place, save the target. 
// you may not need parent(). I was using a UI slider and needed it.

$(".section").mousedown( function(e) {
    thisTarget = $(e.target.parent().attr('id');
    console.log(thisTarget);
});

// anywhere on the page... 
$(document).mouseup( function(e) { 
    // because I'll make it null after every mouseup event.
    if (thisTarget !== null) { 
        console.log( $("#" + thisTarget) ); // returns element
        // do something with it
        thisTarget = null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern correct answer seems to be to use `setPointerCapture`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture

This will let you receive e.g. mouse coordinates while the mouse is outside the browser window (and the `mouseup` event, of course).

Comment: Interesting stuff, thanks. This is not even very new.